# linear regression lines with different colours other than shapes

Tags: r, ggplot2, linear-regression

I have a dataset of 20 points which is grouped in 2 groups (10 each) where in the scatterplot they are coloured the same, but shape is closed and open. However I would like to have the 2 regression lines a different colour and line thickness. Ive found a lot of [info](https://stulp.gmw.rug.nl/ggplotworkshop/twocontinuousvariables.html) but somehow cant get it to work.

Data:

```
df <- data.frame("Group" = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2),
                 "Subject" = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
                 "Method1" = c(2,5,6,8,9,10,15,20,30,40,3,5,6,8,11,14,18,90,22,23),
                 "Method2" = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,23,33,35,40,45,60,80,90,100,111))
```

This works but so with 2 same coloured lines and same thickeness

```
my.formula <-  y ~ x 

LM_plot <- ggplot(df, aes(x=Method1, y=Method2, color=as.character(Group), shape=as.character(Group)))+
  geom_point(aes(size=as.character(Group))) + 
  geom_smooth(method="lm", se = F, fullrange = T) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(18, 5)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#66ccfe", "#66ccfe")) +
  scale_size_manual(values = c(5, 5)) +
  scale_x_continuous("Method1") +
  scale_y_continuous("Method2") +
  stat_poly_eq(aes(label = paste0("atop(", ..eq.label.., ",", ..rr.label.., ")")), 
               formula = my.formula, 
               parse = TRUE, size = 8)
```

[image]

I thought this was the solution but get an error:

Error in `check_aesthetics()`:
! Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (20): x and y
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

```
    my.formula <-  y ~ x 

LM_plot <- ggplot(df, aes(x=Method1, y=Method2, color=Group, shape=Group))+
  geom_point(aes(size=Group), inherit.aes=T) + 
  #geom_smooth(method="lm", se = F, fullrange = T) +
  geom_smooth(aes(x=df$Method1[1:10], y=df$Method2[1:10]), method="lm", se=T, inherit.aes=F, colour="blue", size=4, fullrange = T, formula = my.formula) +
  geom_smooth(aes(x=df$Method1[11:20], y=df$Method2[11:20]), method="lm", se=T, inherit.aes=F, colour="blue", size=2, fullrange = T, formula = my.formula) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(18, 5)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#66ccfe", "#66ccfe")) +
  scale_size_manual(values = c(5, 5)) +
  scale_x_continuous("Method1") +
  scale_y_continuous("Method2") +
  stat_poly_eq(aes(label = paste0("atop(", ..eq.label.., ",", ..rr.label.., ")")), 
               formula = my.formula, 
               parse = TRUE, size = 8)

LM_plot <- LM_plot + theme_prism(base_size = 20)
```

Comment: you are using `scale_color_manual(values = c("#66ccfe", "#66ccfe"))` which are, as far as I am concerned, two very similar colors

Comment: you can change line thickness with the size aesthetic in geom_smooth

Comment: Yes I want to have the scatters the same colours "#66ccfe"...but the regression lines should be dark blue...and scale_color_manual can only be used once......and yes I get it to change everything in aesthetic...but the point is that I cant get 2 regressions lines for the 2 groups in the plot via geom_smooth where I can edit the lines indeed via aesthetic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify color outside of aes, or, if you want to map different scales to the same aesthetic, use ggnewscale (see below).

You can do the same with your size aesthetic.

```r
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame("Group" = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2),
                 "Subject" = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
                 "Method1" = c(2,5,6,8,9,10,15,20,30,40,3,5,6,8,11,14,18,90,22,23),
                 "Method2" = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,23,33,35,40,45,60,80,90,100,111)) 
my.formula <-  y ~ x 

ggplot(df, aes(x=Method1, y=Method2, shape=as.character(Group)))+
  ## use color outside aes
  geom_point(aes(size=as.character(Group)), color = "#66ccfe") + 
  ## add size outside of aes
  geom_smooth(method="lm", se = F, fullrange = T, color = "darkblue", size = 2) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(18, 5)) +
  scale_size_manual(values = c(5, 5)) 
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

two scales for the same aesthetic

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=Method1, y=Method2, shape=as.character(Group)))+
  # use color outside aes
  geom_point(aes(size=as.character(Group), color = I("#66ccfe"))) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(18, 5)) +
  scale_size_manual(values = c(5, 5)) +
  ggnewscale::new_scale_color() +
  ggnewscale::new_scale("size") +
  # now add color into aes
  geom_smooth(aes(color = as.character(Group), size = as.character(Group)),
              method="lm", se = F, fullrange = T) +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set1") +
  scale_size_manual(values = c(1:2))
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

Comment: Thx but I dont fully understand how ggnewscale works (honestly its github doesnt really clarify it to me ;)....so regarding differnet sizes I assume I need to add new_scale("size") after geom_smooth.....but still I dont get it where I need to add the differnet sizes (4 and 2)

Comment: @H.berg check the update.

Comment: ahhhh right i guess it start making sense ;)....so last question...whats the difference of editing a scale inside or outside aes()

Comment: @H.berg aes will dynamically map your variable to the data, and scale maps the "look" to the aesthetic defined within aes(). If you pass the graph's aesthetic outside the aes call, it will be a constant and not changeable with scale().